# Regexp for multiple line C macro in Python

Tags: python, regex, macros

I am trying to delete macros from C headers but I have problem with deleting multiple line macros. So for example

```
#define macro(char)  \
//macro still continues \
//macro still continues \
```

This is regexp for deleting one-line macros but I am not quite sure how to include \n in regular expression.

```
text=re.sub('#([\W\w\s\d])*?\n', '', text, re.S)
```

Comment: Are you also trying to remove other preprocessor constructs, for example, conditional compilation (``#ifdef`` et al)? Your current regular expression will do so, but the question only mentions macros.

Comment: Yes I want to erase ALL macros. This currently erases only oneline macros such as #include "library.h". I am just not quite sure how to put \\n in regexp and it should work for every macro then

Comment: Nitpicking, but clarity is important to get good answers: I think you mean you want to erase all *preprocessor directives*. A macro (``#define ...``) is a type of directive, as is source inclusion (``#include ...``) and conditional inclusion (``#ifdef ... #endif``). See the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) article on Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, didn't read it carefully. as far as conditional inclusions are concerned I want to erase just #ifdef & #endif but not code between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text=re.sub('#([\W\w\s\d])*?(\n.*?\\\\)*\n', '', text, re.S | re.M)
```

should do the trick

**EDIT:** fix by @Blackie123

Comment: Not 100% correct but more than enough to help me make it work, thanks.

Comment: just for other people. this is the working one:
text=re.sub('#([\W\w\s\d])*?(\n.*?\\\\\)*\n', '', text, re.S | re.M)

Comment: yes, you are right. I forgot that the re engine needs double-backslashes too... The other solution is to use a raw string (r'...')

Answer (score 0):

```
text=re.sub(r'^\s*#(?:.*\\\r?\n)*.*$', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

This one is deleting all multiline macros in a text. There is a **\r?\n** for compatibility with windows line endings. One important thing is writing **"flags="** before flags, because fourth argument in re.sub() is a count, so accepted answer above is quiet wrong and method is interpreting specified flags as a count argument.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

[Bug in Python Regex? (re.sub with re.MULTILINE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082886/bug-in-python-regex-re-sub-with-re-multiline)