# Bug in Python Regex? (re.sub with re.MULTILINE)

Tags: python, regex

I'm noticing some odd behavior in Python's Regex library, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

If I run a regex on it using `re.sub()`, with `re.MULTILINE`. It seems to only replace the first few occurrences. It replaces all occurrences if I turn off `re.MULTILINE`, use `re.subn(..., count = 0, flags = re.MULTILINE)`, or compile the regex using `re.compile(..., re.MULTILINE)`.

I am running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've posted a random example on:

- [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/49SU8Mm2) - Output from terminal
- [codepad](http://codepad.org/2RO2iS4O) - Script, confirming behavior (except for re.subn(), which is different on 2.5)

Can someone confirm / deny this behavior on their machine?

EDIT: Realized I should go ahead and post this on the Python bug tracker.
EDIT 2: Issue reported: http://bugs.python.org/msg168909

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use

```
re.sub(pattern, replace, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

instead of

```
re.sub(pattern, replace, text, re.MULTILINE)
```

which is equivalent to

```
re.sub(pattern, replace, text, count=re.MULTILINE)
```

which is a bug in your code.

See [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Ah, well, that explains it haha. I've closed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I was using `re.I` without `flags=` for quite some time and didn't know this. Docs do not warn you about such behaviour which I think is a serious mistake. I don't even remember seeing anybody using `flags` and `count` explicitly.

Comment: @minerals: if you click the link in the answer; you should see `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` function signature and the docs explain what `count` parameter means.