# Python re.sub multiline on string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I try to use the flag **re.MULTILINE**.

I read these posts : [Bug in Python Regex? (re.sub with re.MULTILINE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082886/bug-in-python-regex-re-sub-with-re-multiline), [Python re.sub MULTILINE caret match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-multiline-caret-match) but it doesn't work.
The code :

```
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':

    txt = "\n\
<?php\n\
/* Multi-line\n\
comment */\n\
$var = 1;\n"
    new_txt = re.sub(r'\/\*[.\n]*?\*\/', '', txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    print("\n=========== TXT ============")
    print(txt)
    print("\n=========== NEW TXT ============")
    print(new_txt)
```

The code output :

```
=========== TXT ============

<?php
/* Multi-line
comment */
$var = 1;


=========== NEW TXT ============

<?php
/* Multi-line
comment */
$var = 1;
```

But **new_txt** should not contains **Multi-line comment**.
I want to get the txt without the Multi-line comment. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to use `re.S` flag not `re.M`, and place dot outside the character class.

Comment: Basicly you want the `[.\n]` to match anything BUT a `*/` right? Why not use `[^\*\/]+`? That would make `\/\*[^\*]*\*\/` match your multi line comment without flags.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to replace `re.MULTILINE` with `re.DOTALL`/`re.S` and move out period outside the character class as inside it, the dot matches a literal `.`.

Note that `re.MULTILINE` only redefines the behavior of `^` and `$` that are forced to match at the start/end of a *line* rather than the whole string. The `re.DOTALL` flag redefines the behavior of `.` inside the pattern **outside the character class only**. It starts matching a newline symbol, too.

So, the regex you could use for the current example: `/\*.*?\*/`. It matches a literal `/*` with `/\*`, then `.*?` matches as few any symbols as possible up to and including `*/` (matched with `\*/`).

See the code demo:

```
txt = """\n\
<?php\n\
/* Multi-line\n\
comment */\n\
$var = 1;\n"""
new_txt = re.sub(r'/\*.*?\*/', '', txt, flags=re.S)
print("\n=========== TXT ============")
print(txt)
print("\n=========== NEW TXT ============")
print(new_txt)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BZo9n8)

However, it is not the best solution, as in most cases multiline comments are very long. The best is an *unrolling-the-loop* technique. The regex above can be "unrolled" like this:

```
/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY2kW7/1)

Comment: Thank you for this great response and the clean regex !

Comment: Just FYI: This solution does not support nested multiline comments.

Comment: @alexroat If you need better performance, use `/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/`

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I had many lines, and my aim was to replace a *known* sentence that could reach over more than one line within this multi-line block. What I had to do was to `re.escape()` the sentence, **no multi-line flags needed**. Also, all of these "" and even "\n" are unneeded in the input if you have the line wrap anyway, and in a multi-line string ("""... ...""").

```
txt = """<?php
/* Multi-line
comment */
$var = 1;"""
new_txt = re.sub(re.escape(r"""/* Multi-line
comment */"""), '', txt)
print("\n=========== TXT ============")
print(txt)
print("\n=========== NEW TXT ============")
print(new_txt)
```

```
>>> print("\n=========== TXT ============")

=========== TXT ============
>>> print(txt)
<?php
/* Multi-line
comment */
$var = 1;
>>> print("\n=========== NEW TXT ============")

=========== NEW TXT ============
>>> print(new_txt)
<?php

$var = 1;
```

Perhaps it helps someone with a problem only near to that in the question.