# re.sub, flags = re.MULTILINE with python 3 on Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, jupyter

I am new to NLP and wanna use python re library to clean emails.
I have checked the answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-with-a-flag-does-not-replace-all-occurrences?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). But I could still not figure out why only the first pattern is filtered out.

```
cleantext = re.sub(r'^From .*\n', '', text, flags = re.MULTILINE)
cleantext = re.sub(r'^To .*\n', '', cleantext, flags = re.MULTILINE)
cleantext = re.sub(r'^Subject .*\n', '', cleantext, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of the `^` that you have for the second and third patterns not applicable there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889952/python-re-sub-multiline-on-string?rq=1   see this answer for more about that;  @coldspeed is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I replace the second parameter as '\n', it works as I want.