# Problem when deleting some text using re.sub on a python script

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pdf

I'm creating an script which extract all the text from a pdf to then process it, so i'm first trying to delete a text to clear the document, but when i do it with python re.sub seems to work only until an especific line.

Can you help me?

This is the pdf
https://fastupload.io/en/jzVkEoqzROsdLGs/file

This is the code

```py
import re
from pypdf import PdfReader
from sys import exit

# Abrir el archivo PDF en modo de lectura binaria
reader = PdfReader("archivo.pdf")
texto_completo = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    texto_completo += page.extract_text() + "\n"
print(texto_completo)

# Borrar texto IT Certification Guaranteed, The Easy Way! (nº pagina)
texto_completo = re.sub(r'(?s)(?=IT Certification Guaranteed, The Easy Way!)(.*?)(\d+)', r"",texto_completo,re.MULTILINE)

print(texto_completo)

#resultado
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as res:
    res.write(texto_completo)

exit()
```

Comment: You'd increase your chances of getting an answer by reduciing the problem to a regex only question: share a snippet of `texto_completo` causing the problem and your expected output

Comment: The thing is with an snippet does not happens, only happens with the full file

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i have found the solution on the following link [Bug in Python Regex? (re.sub with re.MULTILINE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082886/bug-in-python-regex-re-sub-with-re-multiline)

```py
import re
from pypdf import PdfReader
from sys import exit

# Abrir el archivo PDF en modo de lectura binaria
reader = PdfReader("archivo.pdf")
texto_completo = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    texto_completo += page.extract_text() + "\n"
print(texto_completo)

# Borrar texto IT Certification Guaranteed, The Easy Way! (nº pagina)
texto_completo = re.sub(r'(?s)(?=IT Certification Guaranteed, The Easy Way!)(.*?)(\d+)', r"",texto_completo,flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(texto_completo)

#resultado
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as res:
    res.write(texto_completo)

exit()
```